# Is there software that allows remote and collaborative work? How is it called?

Tags: terminology

I am currently not in the game development industry and develop my own games using GameMaker, but as a high school student I don't really have the time to make proper titles and actually make money from them. But, I have been thinking. Is there a program/website that, just say you were doing a long distance development with multiple team members in different parts of the world/country, you can upload all your work and with the click of a button anyone else in the "group" automatically downloads it. So for example:

- You are a coder working on the physics engine.
- There is another coder (somewhere else in the world) that is in your group and is programming the player that relies of the physics engine.
- You make a change to the physics engine
- Instead of having to email your partner the updated coding file and him having to download it, you save your file to a program that automatically uploads it to a server
- Every 5 minutes (or whatever) the server checks if either person has uploaded any new files and automatically downloads them and overwrites them
- So in turn your partner stays with continuously updated code and so do you. This could work with any aspect of a game (or any group project).

So is there anything like this? If so, is there a name for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this wonder invention, its called source control.

Many of us use github or visual studio online, if you want auto updates there are a ton of examples for writing about 10 lines of code in a python script or similar to auto fetch and compile sources from a repo, virtually all open source builds do that these days for software that runs on nas or media centers.

On top of that there's then project management tooling like, jira (seems to be the most popular from what i've seen, when used with something like jenkins (an automated build tool) and bitbucket (atlassian's version of github) you can a pretty good continuous integration (CI) workflow for your CI builds.

Pick your poison and do some research.

Comment: But these are all not really gamedev-related, if you're a developer you should've heard about them @Zaxter5. One addition: If you don't want to use free git-hosters you can check out GitLab, it's essentially a software like GitHub (with less features of course) but it runs on your own server.

Comment: @tkausl "gamedev-related" ... neither is GitLab, also my answer was based on commonly accepted answers to the question I felt was asked, although Zaxter said he wanted game software I thought he really meant project related software based on the content of the question thus my recommendations. To my knowledge there is no such thing as "git for just gamedev", or "issue tracking for just gamedev", these are more general programming / project management type concerns.

Comment: @Wardy This was for him, not you. Your Answer is good, i voted up, however i was surprised that he didn't knew those tools since one who wants to start with game-development should have a basic understanding in programming. (And which programmer doesn't know git? ;)

Comment: Yeh I wondered that too ... but I see this all the time, I've been training a guy at work (on my day job) that has more experience than me and has no clue about some of this stuff that I just assumed was common knowledge. The latest generation of programmers don't appear to want to read any more ... frustrating!

Comment: Did I mention I am a high school student or did no one pick that up?

Comment: you're about 5 minutes worth of good guidance behind some guys with 15 years experience :)

Comment: GitHub's issue tracker is also fairly popular as an issue tracker (mainly because it's free and convenient?)